# how to get the uploaded image path in php and ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, file-upload

i have a simple form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" class="picture_main">
<input type="submit" name="upload_picture" id="upload_picture" value="Submit">
```

i am trying to to an ajax upload:

```
submit.on("click", function(){
        var file = $('#file_upload').val();
        uploadImageAjax(file);
        return false;
});

var uploadmageAjax = function(file)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test/index/imageupload",
        data: {
            'file': file
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

what i get back is, for example,  `file: "C:\fakepath\weirdan003-10.jpeg"`

but im not sure what that `fakepath` is !?

if i were to do it in php only i would get the image like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload_picture']) ) {
            $data = $formImageUpload->getValues();
            $pictureName = $data['picture'];
....
```

and then upload it.

So what i want to figure out is if the ajax call POST's to that action the right file so i can then upload it to the disk.

will `$('#file_upload').val();` hold the $_FILE??

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var file = $('#file_upload').val();
```

This will return only a path to file on client machine. for securit reason  it is returned like c:\fakepath\file_name.ext. If I remember correctly, in some older browsers it was possible to get a real path. But still, it does not helps you to get a file on server.

For ajax style upload you can use some of plugins you got recommended. Or just use [jQuery Forms](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin. It will work very similar to `$.ajax`.

Now, when file is uploaded correctly, you will find all required info about it in `$_FILES`

In your case it will be something like `$_FILES['file_upload']` where 'file_upload' is a name of your file input.

Now you can move it from temporary storage with [move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). And do whatever you want with that file

**EDIT:**
And I see you are using Zend. Take a look at [this](http://ahsangill.wordpress.com/2009/02/17/zend-framework-file-upload-using-zend_form_element_file/) about how to work with FileUpload element on the server side. With Zend you may use FileUpload methods instead of move_uploaded_file

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax does not support asynchronous file uploads. See [jQuery upload file using jQuery's ajax method (without plugins)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591291/jquery-upload-file-using-jquerys-ajax-method-without-plugins).

If you want to use ajax file upload, it is recommended to implement plugins:

- http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ (is my favorite)
- http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/ lists several more

Answer (score 0):

For client side, I suggest you to use a plugin.

- http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
- http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

For server side, you will need to handle it to read from the stream. I think there is a full example (client and server side) on [valums git](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader).